# Continuous random vector with joint pdf (find marginal and validity)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let (X,Y) be a continuous random vector with joint probability density function
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
6xy & for \; 0<x<1, 0<y<\sqrt{x}\\ 
 0& otherwise 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that it is a valid joint pdf and that the marginal pdf's are given by
$$f_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
3x^2 & for \; 0<x<1\\ 
 0& otherwise 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
and
$$f_{Y}(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
3y(1-y^4) & for \; 0<y<1\\ 
 0& otherwise 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

**My try**

I would think that to show that it is indeed a valid joint pdf I would have to show the double integral over both variables from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is equal to 1. Would this be it?

For the marginal pdf's I am thinking that I should take the integral from $0$ to $1$ with respect to the variable of the pdf that I am not interested in. I.e for pdf for $X$ i want to integrate over $y$. Would this be correct?
I need this for the next part to find $P(Y>X^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_{XY}(x,y)$ is a valid pdf because $f(x,y)\geq 0$ $\forall (x,y)$ and

$$\int_0^1 6x\left[\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}y dy\right]dx=1$$

To calculate the marginals, simply integrate $f(x,y)$ w.r.t. the other variable

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{y^2}^1 6xy dx$$

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} 6xy dy$$

---

Here is a drawing of the suppport; this will help to understand the solution

[image]

Comment: Seems like I was on the right track but I am still missing why your upper and lower bounds arent 0 to 1 for all of the integrals?

Comment: @user879295 integrating in [0;1] looks like the support is a rectangle but it is not. Wait a few minutes, let me post a draw of the support to clarify the solution...

Comment: @user879295 edited. I hope this helps

Comment: May I ask how one would decide $P(Y>X^2)$? The squared notation is new to me.

Comment: @user879295 I am not sure to have completely understood you question. Following the drawing, when you integrate in $dx$ (horizontally) to find $f_Y$ you integrate in $[y^2;1]$. When you integrate vertically (in $dy$) to find $f_X$ you integrate in $[0;\sqrt(x)]$. Hope now it is clear

Comment: Oh no I am sure it is unrelated to the integrals as that was made very clear! thanks! I just have to find the probability of $P(Y>X^2)$ which does not make sense to me.

Comment: Last question: I still am unsure on how you got the bounds for the marginal for $Y$. I see them directly for $X$ since they are given in the function but why the square of $y$ to $1$.

Comment: @user879295 : to finally clarify the question I added a further answer...hope now it is clear. If still it is not, I think you have to review the basics of double integration

Answer (score 1):

in order to finally clarify the question, have a look at the following drawings

[image]

- In the left picture, when you want to derive $f_X(x)$ you integrate $dy$, in fuction of $X$  thus your integral bounds are $y \in [0;\sqrt{x}]$
- In the right picture, when you want to derivee $f_Y(y)$ you integrate in $dx$, in function of $Y$ thus your integration bouds are $x \in [y^2;1]$

Comment: In order to find the marginal p.d.f. of $X$ , we need to integrate the joint p.d.f. $f(x,y)$ over  the support of $y$. I am with you so far. That is why I See choosing $0<y<\sqrt{x}$ in the one for the pdf of $Y$. I do not know where the $y^2$ is from?

Comment: @user879295 take $y=\sqrt{x}$ and invert it solving in $x=?$

Comment: Well I know what it is ($y^2$) but do not get why we have to do this. In that case; why is the upper bound 1?

Comment: @user879295 : look at the arrows in the second picture... x is between the blue curve and  1

Comment: Thanks got it now!